# Multiple reducers for the same state

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a redux application where i initially async fetch some messages from my server.

I've hooked up the app to a signalR connection, and when the user submits a message, i need to to be added to the Redux state.
However it seems like i cant update the state, or at least im doing it wrong.

When the server send a new message to the client i call my action `addMessagesSignalR`

```
store.dispatch(addMessagesSignalR(messageFromServer));
```

The action is

```
export function addMessagesSignalR(Obj) {
let messageFromServer = Obj;
   return {
     type: 'FETCH_MESSAGES_SIGNALR',
     payload: messageFromServer
   };
}
```

And my reducer is:

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_MESSAGES':
        return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
    case 'FETCH_MESSAGES_SIGNALR':
        return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
}
return state;
```

}

Im trying to merge the state of the fetched messages with the message recieved from signalR in my rootReducer:

```
messages: fetchMessages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is used to merge objects, but your state appears to be an array.  You need to use different syntax to merge arrays.

ES6 (using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)):

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_MESSAGES':
        return [...state, action.payload];
    case 'FETCH_MESSAGES_SIGNALR':
        return [...state, action.payload]
}
return state;
```

ES5 (using [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=a)):

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_MESSAGES':
        return state.concat(action.payload);
    case 'FETCH_MESSAGES_SIGNALR':
        return state.concat(action.payload)
}
return state;
```